# Using variable in instance name of text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, widget

I am trying to use a variable in a textbox instance name in order to shuffle through them in a for loop.  For example, I have 14 text widgets(infoBox1 to InfoBox14) that I am trying to fill from a list.  So what I am looking to do is the following:

```
x=1
for item in finalList:

     self.infoBox(x).insert(END, item)

     x += 1
```

Then just populate the boxes as x increases.   Can someone help with this?

Comment: Your question is "is it possible", and the answer is, more than likely "yes".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need names to do such thing. You can put your widgets in a list then access those using indexes.

```
#you can create like this. Used -1 as index to access last added text widget
text_list = []
for idx in range(14):
    text_list.append(tkinter.Text(...))
    text_list[-1].grid(...)

#then you can easily select whichever you want just like accessing any item from a list

text_list[x].insert(...)
#or directly
for idx, item in enumerate(finalList):
    text_list[idx].insert("end", item)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you are trying to do.

I have not come across a situation that would need to do it this way though.

Here is an example using `exec` to perform the commands per loop.

For more on the `exec` statement you can reed some documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html)

NOTE: Avoid this method and use the list/dict methods instead. This example is just to provide knowledge on how it would be possible in python.

```
from tkinter import *

class tester(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)       

        self.parent = parent
        self.ent0 = Entry(self.parent)
        self.ent1 = Entry(self.parent)
        self.ent2 = Entry(self.parent)
        self.ent0.pack()
        self.ent1.pack()
        self.ent2.pack()

        self.btn1 = Button(self.parent, text="Put numbers in each entry with a loop", command = self.number_loop)
        self.btn1.pack()

    def number_loop(self):
        for i in range(3):
            exec ("self.ent{}.insert(0,{})".format(i, i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = tester(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While you are at it, you can create entries with exec as well. :)

Comment: True. I just wanted to address the insert function that the OP was using.